# React native linker command failed for libRNLaunchNavigator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native

I've faced this issue and i don't know why?
[image]

Comment: do you have a .Project.xcworkspace in ios folder? if you have close u project and open it

Comment: @ahmet I just have these two files : LuckyHouse.xcodeproj and LuckyHouse.xcworkspace

Comment: close your project and open the LuckyHouse.xcworkspace

Comment: @ahmet I know and i'm using . xcworkspace but still i see this error